# Pushing elements onto an array not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to build dynamic arrays based on a field in my database. The purpose is so that I can compare those arrays to ensure that they don't each contain certain data. This is a race track scoring app, I need to make sure that race classes don't have entries in back to back classes.

The echo below outputs the data as I expected it would, however, when I try to push those rows from the database into arrays based on the class_id, it fails.

See the output below. What am I missing here?
(note, I didn't bring all of the data to this party, way too much to copy and paste)

```
function getEventClasses()
{
    global $db;
    global $event_id;
    try {
        $getEventClasses = $db->prepare('SELECT class_id
                                         FROM tbl_event_classes
                                         WHERE event_id = :event_id
                                         ORDER BY sort');
        $getEventClasses->bindValue(':event_id', $event_id);
        $getEventClasses->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo 'An Error occurred!<br>';
        //user friendly message
        $ex->getMessage();
        echo $ex;
        exit;
    }
    $eventClasses = [];
    while ($r = $getEventClasses->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $eventClasses[] = [
            'class_id' => $r['class_id']
        ];
    }
    return $eventClasses;
}
function getEntries($class_id)
{
    global $db;
    global $event_id;
    global $f;
    try {
        $getEntries = $db->prepare('SELECT tbl_event_entries.racer_id, 
                                       tbl_event_entries.class_id, 
                                       tbl_event_entries.event_id, 
                                       tbl_event_classes.class_type, 
                                       tbl_event_classes.points_class, 
                                       tbl_moto_order.moto_nbr
                                FROM tbl_moto_order 
                                INNER JOIN (tbl_event_entries 
                                 LEFT JOIN tbl_event_classes 
                                        ON (tbl_event_entries.event_id = tbl_event_classes.event_id)
                                        AND (tbl_event_entries.class_id = tbl_event_classes.class_id)) 
                                        ON (tbl_moto_order.class_id = tbl_event_entries.class_id)
                                        AND (tbl_moto_order.event_id = tbl_event_entries.event_id)
                                WHERE tbl_event_entries.event_id = :event_id
                                AND tbl_event_entries.racer_id != "9999"
                                AND tbl_event_entries.class_id = :class_id');
        $getEntries->bindValue(':event_id', $event_id);
        $getEntries->bindValue(':class_id', $class_id);
        $getEntries->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo 'An Error occurred!<br>';
        //user friendly message
        $ex->getMessage();
        echo $ex;
        exit;
    }
    $eventEntries = [];
    while ($r = $getEntries->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $eventEntries[] = [
        'racer_id'     => $r['racer_id'],
        'class_id'     => $r['class_id'],
        'event_id'     => $r['event_id'],
        'class_type'   => $r['class_type'],
        'points_class' => $r['points_class'],
        'moto_nbr'     => $r['moto_nbr']
        ];
    }
    return $eventEntries;
}


$eventClasses = getEventClasses();
foreach ($eventClasses as $eventClass) {

        $eventEntries = getEntries($eventClass['class_id']);

        foreach ($eventEntries as $eventEntry) {

            echo ' class_id : ', $eventClass['class_id'],
            ' | racer_id : ', $eventEntry['racer_id'],
            ' | event_id : ', $eventEntry['event_id'],
            ' | class_type : ', $eventEntry['class_type'],
            ' | points_class : ', $eventEntry['points_class'],
            ' | moto_nbr : ', $eventEntry['moto_nbr'],
            '<br>';

            array_push($runningClasses[$eventClass['class_id']],
                $eventEntry['racer_id'],
                $eventEntry['event_id'],
                $eventEntry['class_type'],
                $eventEntry['points_class'],
                $eventEntry['moto_nbr']);

        }

}
```

output of echo:

```
class_id : 17 | racer_id : 95 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 17 | moto_nbr : 3
class_id : 17 | racer_id : 350 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 17 | moto_nbr : 3
class_id : 17 | racer_id : 493 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 17 | moto_nbr : 3
class_id : 17 | racer_id : 295 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 17 | moto_nbr : 3
class_id : 14 | racer_id : 1142 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 14 | moto_nbr : 4
class_id : 14 | racer_id : 162 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 14 | moto_nbr : 4
class_id : 14 | racer_id : 151 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 14 | moto_nbr : 4
class_id : 14 | racer_id : 1176 | event_id : 326 | class_type : A | points_class : 14 | moto_nbr : 4
```

contents of $runningclasses:

```
Array
(
[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 295
        [1] => 326
        [2] => A
        [3] => 17
        [4] => 3
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1125
        [1] => 326
        [2] => A
        [3] => 14
        [4] => 4
    )

)
```

I'm only getting the last eventEntry in each eventClass in the runningClasses array.

Thanks to Manjeet Barnala for reminding me of this.. Below is the working foreach loop I am now using:

```
foreach ($eventClasses as $eventClass) {
    $eventEntries = getEntries($eventClass['class_id']);
      foreach ($eventEntries as $eventEntry) {
        $runningClasses[$eventClass['class_id']][] = [
            $eventEntry['racer_id'],
            $eventEntry['event_id'],
            $eventEntry['class_type'],
            $eventEntry['points_class'],
            $eventEntry['moto_nbr']
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing $runningClasses[$eventClass['class_id']] properly to an empty array before pushing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this code with your array push and declare `$runningClasses=array();` an empty array  on the top of function..

```
$arr = array();
$arr['racer_id'] = $eventEntry['racer_id'];
$arr['event_id'] = $eventEntry['event_id'];
$arr['class_type'] = $eventEntry['class_type'];
$arr['points_class']= $eventEntry['points_class'];
$arr['moto_nbr']= $eventEntry['moto_nbr']);

$runningClasses[$eventClass['class_id']][] = $arr;
```

Comment: I did that and got the exact same result.

Comment: @indymx, okay .. add an extra index `[ ] ` for multiple values of one class id, previously it was only for one, I've edited the answer try now....

Comment: Ahhh.. yes, that's it. I know for a fact I have done this before in several places in this app, but for some reason was experiencing a brain block on this one.

Thanks a lot Manjeet

Comment: I updated the original post to include the working loop.

Comment: yeah.. I've seen, and thank you for appreciation. I'm always here to help... anytime :)